# Relative imports error. How to import files from higher level directory in the python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, relative-import

Below is the **directory structure** -

```sh
./remote-control-spotify
├── client
│   ├── menu_item.py
│   └── panel.py
├── config.yaml
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── pyotify
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── auth_method.py
│   │   ├── authorization.py
│   │   ├── auth.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── core
│       ├── album.py
│       ├── artist.py
│       ├── config.py
│       ├── exceptions.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── parameter.py
│       ├── player.py
│       ├── request.py
│       ├── request_type.py
│       ├── search.py
│       └── search_type.py
├── README.md
├── spotify_auth.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Below is the python code for **relative imports** from **spotify_auth.py** which throws an error.

```py
from .pyotify.core.config import read_config
from .pyotify.core.exceptions import BadRequestError
from .pyotify.auth.authorization import Authorization
from .pyotify.auth.auth import get_auth_key
```

And here's the **relative imports error** that's thrown when trying `python spotify_auth.py`

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/spotify_auth.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .pyotify.core.config import read_config
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Now, after I tried modifying the imports as below -

```py
from pyotify.core.config import read_config
from pyotify.core.exceptions import BadRequestError
from pyotify.auth.authorization import Authorization
from pyotify.auth.auth import get_auth_key
```

Yet there's an error as shown below -

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/spotify_auth.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyotify.core.config import read_config
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/pyotify/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import read_config
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/pyotify/core/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyotify.auth import authMethod
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/pyotify/auth/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .auth import authenticate
  File "/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/pyotify/auth/auth.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pyotify.core import BadRequestError
ImportError: cannot import name 'BadRequestError' from partially initialized module 'pyotify.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/prithvi/Desktop/remote-control-spotify/pyotify/core/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pyotify.core.config import read_config
from pyotify.core.exceptions import BadRequestError
from pyotify.auth.authorization import Authorization
from pyotify.auth.auth import get_auth_key
```

Comment: I get the following error - 
`importError: cannot import name 'BadRequestError' from partially initialized module 'pyotify.core' (most likely due to a circular import)`